# cakephp save numeric value as string

Tags: php, mysql, sql, cakephp

My table confirmed value is ENUM('0', '1'). So i want to generate insert query after form submit. I need following query.

```
INSERT INTO `woa`.`original_weights` (`weight`, `user_id`, `confirmed`, `modified`, `created`) 
VALUES (123, 2, 9, '1', '2014-06-04 06:41:27', '2014-06-04 06:41:27')
```

But it generate following query with out wrapping quote for 1.

```
INSERT INTO `woa`.`original_weights` (`weight`, `user_id`, `confirmed`, `modified`, `created`) 
VALUES (123, 2, 9, 1, '2014-06-04 06:41:27', '2014-06-04 06:41:27')
```

(Check '1' and 1). So confirmed value always save as 0.

This is my action.

```
if ($this->request->is('post')) {
    $data = $this->request->data['DataOriginal'];

    $data['user_id'] = $this->Auth->User('id');
    $data['confirmed'] = '1';
    $data['type'] = 'M';

    $this->loadModel('DataOriginal');

    $this->DataOriginal->create();

    if ($this->DataOriginal->save($data)) {
    }
}
```

When i use

```
$data['confirmed'] = '1'; //result VALUES (123, 2, 9, 1,
```

confirmed value save as 0

```
$data['confirmed'] = "'1'"; //result VALUES (123, 2, 9, "\'1\'",
```

confirmed value save as '' (null)

How can i success this query?

Comment: Your value of `confirmed` is boolean, right? if so, you can change your type of `confirmed` to `tinyint(1)`. the cakephp will handle for your 0 and 1 OR false and true for you.

Comment: Yes. I know. But i cant change the database. I should use ENUM()

Comment: @Asuraya : Please try with  $data['confirmed'] = "'1'"; Let me know any way.

Comment: Yes. I already tried it. It generate '\'1\'' . It will not update clearly.

Comment: Try $data['confirmed'] = intval($data['confirmed']); and check if it helps you.

Comment: what error you got or confirmed is not saving 1?Auery may run perfectly

Comment: I didn't get an error. But I cant save correct value to confirmed column. Please check my question again. I add new lines to describe the result.

Comment: There is nothing wrong in using '1' & 1. Both gets saved as 1 since you have specified enum in the table. Something must be wrong with your value getting saved. Just check with data ie.,$data before saving. If you still find it not working, change your datatype of the specific column to int(2). It should work